# Is there a way to write less repetitive code? Writing an XML file in python using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I am currently learning to code in python, but working with XML files is giving me some trouble. I tried to write an XML-file using some data that i filtered from a JSON-file.

The XML-file I want to write should look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<collection>
    <work>
        <title>Title</title>
        <dimensions>
            <width>Width (cm)</width>
            <height>Height (cm)</height>
        </dimensions>
        <acquisition>
            <number>AccessionNumber</number>
            <year>year of DateAcquired</year>
        </acquisition>
    </work>
  [...]
</collection>
```

It can be written into one line in the XML, since it doesn't need to be pretty.

My python code at the moment is looking like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element('collection')
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

for artwork in artworks_filtered_list:
    work = ET.SubElement(root, 'work')
    title = ET.SubElement(work, 'title')
    title.text = artwork['Title']
    dimensions = ET.SubElement(work, 'dimensions')
    if 'Width (cm)' in artwork:
        width = ET.SubElement(dimensions, 'width')
        width.text = str(artwork['Width (cm)'])
    height = ET.SubElement(dimensions, 'height')
    height.text = str(artwork['Height (cm)'])
    acquisition = ET.SubElement(work, 'acquisition')
    number = ET.SubElement(acquisition, 'number')
    number.text = str(artwork['AccessionNumber'])
    year = ET.SubElement(acquisition, 'year')
    year.text = str(artwork['DateAcquired'][:4])

tree.write('example.xml', encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Since width is missing in some artwork data, I needed to check if it exists for each entry. Otherwise I get an error message.
artworks_filtered_list is a list of dictionaries that contains entries for different artworks and is looking like this:

```
artworks_filtered_list = [
    {
        "Title": "Interval",
        "Artist": ["David Hartt"],
        "ConstituentID": [47183],
        "ArtistBio": ["Canadian, born 1967"],
        "Nationality": ["Canadian"],
        "BeginDate": [1967],
        "EndDate": [0],
        "Gender": ["Male"],
        "Date": "2016",
        "Medium": "Aluminum and tempered glass",
        "Dimensions": 'Wall: 102 × 218 × 4" (259.1 × 553.7 × 10.2 cm)',
        "CreditLine": "Fund for the Twenty First Century",
        "AccessionNumber": "1772.2015.5",
        "Classification": "Installation",
        "Department": "Media and Performance Art",
        "DateAcquired": "2015-12-11",
        "Cataloged": "Y",
        "ObjectID": 205745,
        "URL": "http://www.moma.org/collection/works/205745",
        "ThumbnailURL": None,
        "Depth (cm)": 10.16002032,
        "Height (cm)": 259.080518161,
        "Width (cm)": 553.7211074422,
    },
    ...,
]
```

This is my code right now. It is working and creating the XML-file as intended, but i feel like there might be more code than needed. Is there a way to get the same result with less repetitive/ prettier code? (It should still use ElementTree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use some sort of mapping to reduce the amount of redundant code. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import datetime

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


artworks_filtered_list = [...as in your example...]


# This by itself reduces the amount of code by about 50% :)
def add_text_element(root, tag, text):
    new = ET.SubElement(root, tag)
    new.text = text


# According to your question, acquisition.year should be just the
# year from DateAcquired, so we need a method to extract and return
# the year.
def extract_year(val):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(val, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return dt.year


# This is called once for every work of art in artworks_filtered_list
def append_work(root, work):

    # create the <work> container element
    new = ET.SubElement(root, 'work')

    # create empty dimension and acquisition elements. This adds them
    # to the new <work> element.
    dimensions = ET.SubElement(new, 'dimensions')
    acquisition = ET.SubElement(new, 'acquisition')

    # Add our title
    add_text_element(new, 'title', work['Title'])

    # Now build a map that will link keys from a work of art in
    # artworks_filtered_list to XML elements. Each item in this list is
    # a 4-tuple, where the items are:
    #
    # 1. The parent element to which we will be adding a new element
    # 2. The name of the new element
    # 3. The dictionary key from which we will get the text value
    # 4. A function to transform the value, if necessary (or None)
    #
    attrmap = [
        (dimensions, 'width', 'Width (cm)', None),
        (dimensions, 'height', 'Height (cm)', None),
        (acquisition, 'number', 'AccessionNumber', None),
        (acquisition, 'year', 'DateAcquired', extract_year),
    ]

    # And now use the above map to transform the artwork dictionary
    # into XML elements.
    for parent, tag, key, xform in attrmap:
        if key in work:
            add_text_element(parent, tag,
                             str(xform(work[key]) if xform else work[key]))


def main():
    root = ET.Element('collection')

    for work in artworks_filtered_list:
        append_work(root, work)

    print(ET.tostring(root).decode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Given your sample input, the above code produces:

```
<collection>
  <work>
    <dimensions>
      <width>553.7211074422</width>
      <height>259.080518161</height>
    </dimensions>
    <acquisition>
      <number>1772.2015.5</number>
      <year>2015</year>
    </acquisition>
    <title>Interval</title>
  </work>
</collection>
```

...although it doesn't actually pretty-print it. If you were to use `lxml.etree` instead of `xml.etree`, `tostring` would be able to pretty-print XML for you.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot, especially your detailed explanation. I just have one question: What exactly does ```if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()``` do? I have not seen something like this before.